Advertising Test Beginning Nov 13 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on November 13, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

I'm not very happy about the communication about this. I cannot be expected to follow all posts on SO, and I'd expect that changes are first communicated to the mod team before being implemented. I cannot currently answer questions about how e.g. the user's privacy is protected (or not) using this scheme and I therefore protest against this action by the SE team under the current moderator agreement. I'm not against it as it is apparently very effective, but this is again all about communication.

Anybody: Feel free to post followup comments here if it is specific to this site; I'll be happy to take it up with the SE team.

As nobody seems to care I am not going to oppose this. I hope it will make SE some money. I'm not going to be against just because, although I think that the communication should still be better and give me some time to be able to ask & answer questions.

In China, the open auction model actually made news for causing death - the Wei Zexi incident.
The story goes, a un-qualified institute posted medical ads in open auction similar to what's proposed here on a search engine, the patient trusted it, went to the so-called hospital, and received mal-treatment and died eventually. Those familiar with the story generally view negatively about that particular search engine and ad auction.
I seriously recommend SO/SE to reconsider whether ad bids are good for the long term.

The idea is apparently to have cryptography specific ads as much as possible. They've seen better returns in hundreds of percent when they tried it on the initial site. That said, if anybody sees dangerous ads please notify the mods immediately or create a meta post. What I understood is that the ads are still screened and not just go to the highest bidder.
